# NSubstitute doesn't substitute method

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I've got my testing target class:

```
public class ApiClient
{

    private IRestClient authz_rest_client;
    private IRestClient api_rest_client;


    // Injection feature for testing
    internal ApiClient(IRestClient authz_rest_client, IRestClient api_rest_client)
    {
        this.authz_rest_client = authz_rest_client;
        this.api_rest_client = api_rest_client;
    }
    //...
```

So, I inject my substituted RestSharp Clients as follows:

```
[TestFixture]
class AuthzApiClientTests
{

    private ApiClient api_client;

    private IRestClient authz_rest_client;
    private IRestClient api_rest_client;

    private IRestRequest request;
    private IRestResponse<OAuth2AuthzCodeResponse> response;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        this.authz_rest_client = NSubstitute.Substitute.For<IRestClient>();
        this.api_rest_client = NSubstitute.Substitute.For<IRestClient>();

        this.request = NSubstitute.Substitute.For<IRestRequest>();
        this.response = NSubstitute.Substitute.For<IRestResponse<OAuth2AuthzCodeResponse>>();

        this.authz_rest_client.Execute<OAuth2AuthzCodeResponse>(request).Returns(response);

        this.api_client = new ApiClient(this.authz_rest_client, this.api_rest_client);
        this.api_client.configure(
            "client_id",
            "user",
            "passwd"
        );
    }
```

Then, I write a test:

```
    [Test]
    public void Should_ReturnCorrectRequestTokenServiceEndpoint()
    {

        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        response.Data = new OAuth2AuthzCodeResponse()
        {
            Error = StringEnum.GetStringValue(OAuth2ErrorTypes.invalid_client)  //CLIENT IS NOT REGISTERED ON LEST SYSTEM.
        };

        this.api_client.Invoking(c => c.GrantAuthorization())
            .ShouldThrow<OAuth2APIException>();
    }
```

As you can see, I want to test my `GrantAuthorization` method of my `ApiClient` class. This method is:

```
IRestRequest authzcode_request = new AuthzCodeRequest(
            this.settings.AuthzAuthorizeEndpoint,
            this.settings.ClientId,
            this.settings.ClientSecret,
            this.settings.User,
            this.settings.Password
        );

        IRestResponse<OAuth2AuthzCodeResponse> authzcode_response = this.authz_rest_client.Execute<OAuth2AuthzCodeResponse>(authzcode_request);
        this.check_response(authzcode_response);

        this.settings.AuthzCode = authzcode_response.Data.Code;
        this.settings.AuthzCodeExpirationThreshold = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(authzcode_response.Data.Expires_in);
```

The target of my test is "capture" my `Execute<OAuth2AuthzCodeResponse>` method in order to return my substituted response.

The problem is that, when I perform the test and I stop on this line, the result is not the response I've set previously.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble following through the full example, but I did notice something about the `SetUp` being using:

```
request = Substitute.For<IRestRequest>();
response = Substitute.For<IRestResponse<OAuth2AuthzCodeResponse>>();
authz_rest_client.Execute<OAuth2AuthzCodeResponse>(request).Returns(response);
```

The third line here says that whenever `authz_rest_client.Execute<OAuth2AuthzCodeResponse>()` is called with the `request` instance, it will return `response`. But `request` never seems to be used anywhere within the code, so `Execute` will never actually return that `response`.

Something like the following line will return `response` for any call to `Execute<OAuth2AuthzCodeResponse>()`:

```
authz_rest_client.Execute<OAuth2AuthzCodeResponse>(null).ReturnsForAnyArgs(response);
```

But I'm not sure that's what you want either? Instead you might want to stub out individual calls, such as a specific response when it gets a request of type `AuthzCodeRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I tried it using that:

```
this.authz_rest_client.Execute<OAuth2AuthzCodeResponse>(Arg.Any<IRestRequest>()).Returns(response);
```

This solution is similar to the pervious answer approach.

However, I not understand why not work perviouly...

Comment: It was not working because the previous code said "whenever this method gets called with 'request', then return 'response'". Then the method was never called with `request`. The new version says "whenever this method gets called with any argument, then return 'response'". As an aside, I'm concerned that always returning the same response is going to lead to ineffective tests. Consider stubbing the client to respond more realistically to different requests.